# MVC C# single regex to validate curly braces and angle brackets

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation

I am trying to make a spinner for one of my projects, and I have a text area and I want to validate text if curly braces are closed and text don't have angle brackets.

So far I am able to check if text has any angle brackets present with `[^<>]*`

I have this string `{hello|hi|hey} arbaz, {how are you?|how you doing}`
and i want to validate if curly braces is closed correctly. for example string can't be

`{{hello|hi|hey}} arbaz, {{how are you?|how you doing}}`

OR

`{{hello|hi|hey} arbaz, {how are you?|how you doing}}`

it can't be wrap in curly brackets.

`\{{?>\{{?<c>}|[^{}]+|\}{?<-c>}}*{?{c}{?!}}\}` is my regex so far.

I need a regex which can validate with curly braces and don't allow the angle brackets. Please forgive me for my bad English. Thanks

Comment: Do I get you right that you want to match a string that contains either chars other than `{` and `}` OR `{...}` substrings and none of these can also match `<` and `>`? Try `^(?:[^<>{}]|{[^<>{}]*})*$`

Comment: See [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3a%5b%5e%3c%3e%7b%7d%5d%7c%7b%5b%5e%3c%3e%7b%7d%5d*%7d%29*%24&i=%7bhello%7chi%7chey%7d+arbaz%2c+%7bhow+are+you%3f%7chow+you+doing%7d%0d%0a%7b%3chello%3e%7chi%7chey%7d+arbaz%2c+%7bhow+are+you%3f%7chow+you+doing%7d%0d%0a%7b%7bhello%7chi%7chey%7d%7d+arbaz%2c+%7b%7bhow+are+you%3f%7chow+you+doing%7cwhat%27s+up%7d%7d%0d%0a%7b%7bhello%7chi%7chey%7d+arbaz%2c+%7bhow+are+you%3f%7chow+you+doing%7cwhat%27s+up%7d%7d%0d%0a&o=m)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks so much for your comment, it is working as like I wanted to curly braces. Can you please add to check if HTML tags are present for example `<>` Thanks

Comment: See my comment above with the link. `{<hello>|hi|hey} arbaz, {how are you?|how you doing}` is not matched because the string contains `<` (and `>` but it is not important already)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to match a string that contains either chars other than `{` and `}` OR `{...}` substrings and none of these can also match `<` and `>` chars.

You may use

```
^(?:[^<>{}]|{[^<>{}]*})*$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3A%5B%5E%3C%3E%7B%7D%5D%7C%7B%5B%5E%3C%3E%7B%7D%5D%2A%7D%29%2A%24&i=%7Bhello%7Chi%7Chey%7D%20arbaz%2C%20%7Bhow%20are%20you%3F%7Chow%20you%20doing%7D%0D%0A%7B%3Chello%3E%7Chi%7Chey%7D%20arbaz%2C%20%7Bhow%20are%20you%3F%7Chow%20you%20doing%7D%0D%0A%7B%7Bhello%7Chi%7Chey%7D%7D%20arbaz%2C%20%7B%7Bhow%20are%20you%3F%7Chow%20you%20doing%7Cwhat%27s%20up%7D%7D%0D%0A%7B%7Bhello%7Chi%7Chey%7D%20arbaz%2C%20%7Bhow%20are%20you%3F%7Chow%20you%20doing%7Cwhat%27s%20up%7D%7D%0D%0A&o=m)

It matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group

  - `[^<>{}]` - any char but `<`, `>`, `{` and `}`
  - `|`  - or
  - `{` - a `{`
  - `[^<>{}]*` - 0+ chars other than `<`, `>`, `{` and `}`
  - `}` - a `}` char
- `)*` - repeat the group pattern 0+ times
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks so much for quick help. God bless.

Comment: if `<...>` are outside the `{...}` then it should give an error.

Comment: @ArbazAbid Currently, the pattern does not allow `<` and `>` anywhere.

Comment: Actually it is allowing.. when I write `<>` outside the curly brackets. It is allowing it.

Comment: @ArbazAbid [It does not](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3a%5b%5e%3c%3e%7b%7d%5d%7c%7b%5b%5e%3c%3e%7b%7d%5d*%7d%29*%24&i=%7bhello%7chi%7chey%7d+%3c%3e&o=m). Show me an example.

Comment: I know on regexstrom it is showing correct, but in testing in my project it is not giving error on `<>` present in the text. Please see this screenshot http://prntscr.com/fyzv4r

Comment: `[RegularExpression("^(?:[^{}]|{[^{}]*})*$", ErrorMessage = "Make sure curly brackets are closed correctly.")]` this is my code for validation for textarea

Comment: the solution `^(?:[^<>{}]|{[^<>{}]*})*$` doesn't work on notepad++ win10

Comment: @JustMe The regex is not supposed to work in NPP at all. It is a validating regex, not extracting or highlighting, and NPP uses Boost regex engine, not .NET one.

Comment: @ArbazAbid Do you mean the `<` and `>` are turned into entities `&lt;` and `&gt;` and thus the regex does not "see" them? Try [`^(?:(?!&[gl]t;)[^{}]|{(?:(?!&[gl]t;)[^{}])*})*$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3a%28%3f!%26%5bgl%5dt%3b%29%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d%7c%7b%28%3f%3a%28%3f!%26%5bgl%5dt%3b%29%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d%29*%7d%29*%24&i=%7bhello%7chi%7chey%7d+%0d%0a%26gt%3b%26lt%3b) to see if I am right in this suspicion. Best is to make sure you run the posted regex against a plain text.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: yes exactly they are changed to `&lt;` and `&gt;`, may be that's why it's not catching them. I am sorry I am taking so much of your time.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Actually I was checking on client side, not on server side. Thanks so much for the brief explanation. Now I am checking on server side and working fine. Thanks again